# How do I set up custom Mongo formatters in Spring?

Tags: spring, mongodb

I've been at this for a few hours and haven't found anyone that's gotten this working yet.  I want to persist a BigDecimal object in Mongo, but Mongo doesn't natively support BigDecimal.  I followed Spring's docs [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/1.0.0.M3/reference/html/#mapping-explicit-converters) but no luck.

From what I can tell Spring isn't injecting my custom converter classes into Mongo when it's writing to the db.  Here's what I have done:

My applicationContext-services.xml
...

```
    <!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
    <mongo:mongo 
        host="localhost" 
        port="1234" />

    <mongo:db-factory 
        dbname="solar" 
        mongo-ref="mongo"/>

    <mongo:mapping-converter>
      <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter>
          <bean class="com.mine.BigDecimalReadConverter"/>
        </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
          <bean class="com.mine..BigDecimalWriteConverter"/>
        </mongo:converter>
      </mongo:custom-converters>
    </mongo:mapping-converter>

    <!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="mongoDbTest"
    class="com.mine.MongoDbTest">
    <property name="mongoTemplate">
        <ref local="mongoTemplate" />
    </property> 
</bean>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple constructors with arguments found in class java.math.BigDecimal! Annotate one with @PreferedConstructor explicitly to select it to be used in persistence operations.
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.<init>(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:81)
```

Comment: You look at the unit tests in spring-data or the module that u are using?

Comment: i have not.  i've set it up as the docs suggest to do but no luck.

Comment: which version of Spring data you are using ??

Comment: if you post your solution as the answer then it'll be easier for other people to find the solution when they are searching (it'll become an "answered question" rather than an unanswered one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this.  The order in which you define the beans matters.  So my app.xml that I got it working with is:

```
 <bean id="mappingContext" class="org.springframework.data.document.mongodb.mapping.MongoMappingContext"/>

<bean id="readConverter"  class="com.mine.BigDecimalReadConverter"/>
<bean id="writeConverter"  class="com.mine.BigDecimalWriteConverter"/>

<mongo:mapping-converter id="mappingConverter">
    <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter ref="readConverter" />
        <mongo:converter ref="writeConverter" />
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>

<!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
<mongo:mongo 
    host="${${environment}.mongodb.host}" 
    port="${${environment}.mongodb.port}" />

<mongo:db-factory 
    dbname="${${environment}.mongodb.databaseName}" 
    mongo-ref="mongo"/>   

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.document.mongodb.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingConverter"/>
</bean>

<!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for converter support:

```
<bean id="mappingContext"
    class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext" lazy-init="true"/>

 <bean id="defaultMongoTypeMapper"
    class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper" lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg name="typeKey"><null/></constructor-arg>
 </bean>

 <bean id="mappingMongoConverter"
    class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter" lazy-init="true" >
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="mappingContext" ref="mappingContext" />
    <property name="typeMapper" ref="defaultMongoTypeMapper" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingMongoConverter" />
 </bean>
```